# why did i get a KeyError: 'Level *** not found'

Tags: pandas

run the following codes

```
def afun(group):
  aa=len(group)
  group.sort_values(inplace=True)

  return pd.DataFrame({'score':np.arange(aa),'price':group})



df = pd.DataFrame({
              'stock':np.repeat( ['AAPL','GOOG','YHOO'], 3 ),
              'date':np.tile( pd.date_range('5/5/2015', periods=3, freq='D'), 3 ),
              'price':(np.random.randn(9).cumsum() + 10) ,
              'price2':(np.random.randn(9).cumsum() + 10)})
df = df.set_index(['stock','date'])
agroupDf=df.groupby(level='date') 



tt=agroupDf['price'].apply(afun)
```

i got a dataframe 'tt'

[image]
[image]

i want to drop the index level date,however ,`tt.reset_index(level='date', drop=True,inplace=True)`give me `KeyError: 'Level date not found'`

i am coufused , how to drop the first date?

the all error message is as follows

```
tt.reset_index(level='date', drop=True,inplace=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-493c886f0c00>", line 1, in <module>
    tt.reset_index(level='date', drop=True,inplace=True)

  File "D:\common\Anaconda3.4\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2920, in reset_index
    level = [self.index._get_level_number(lev) for lev in level]

  File "D:\common\Anaconda3.4\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2920, in <listcomp>
    level = [self.index._get_level_number(lev) for lev in level]

  File "D:\common\Anaconda3.4\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\multi.py", line 519, in _get_level_number
    raise KeyError('Level %s not found' % str(level))

KeyError: 'Level date not found'
```

Comment: The index names are `'date'`, `'stock'` and `'date'`. There is no `'tradeDate'`. What precisely do you want to achieve? Your code is so convoluted. It is doing the same thing 2 times...

Comment: @Kartik i am sorry , the 'tradeDate' is a mistake .i will edit .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why groupby.apply return duplicate level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948336/why-groupby-apply-return-duplicate-level)

Comment: This the same question asked/answered here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948336/why-groupby-apply-return-duplicate-level

Comment: @Merlin. No ,its not the same question .I use the same codes ,but i met the different problem when i learn pandas .  the first one is  i don't know why two 'date' appears,the second question is why i cannot drop the date evenif the date is a level of the index.

Comment: Well use the code that I fixed for you, why do you continue to use broken /unstructured code?  It is the same problem, you are trying figure out code that you didnt write, if you did write this.. please take a tutorial..

Comment: i did write this 。i  am trying to understand dataframe ,multiIndex .So i am trying different test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121132/discussion-between-inaminute-and-merlin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is not `KeyError: 'Level date not found'`, it is `ValueError: The name date occurs multiple times, use a level number`. And as the error suggests:

```
tt.reset_index(level=2, drop=True,inplace=True)
```

will give you what you want.

Comment: yes ,you are  right . Thanks a lot . 
I'm stuck in this trouble for a long time。would you tell me where to find the error suggestion you just mention

Comment: @inaMinute, step back a take a tutorial on python topics that interest you. You need to follow someones lead.... what your doing is unpythonic and unreadable by experienced python dev's.

Comment: @Merlin, I was trying to offer OP a Pythonic way of achieving the goal. However, I am running a bit late. If you are around, feel free to edit my answer or post a new one with a better way of getting the results the OP is looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Merlin . Thanks for your suggestion ,i will try what you said .

Comment: @inaMinute, Merlin's answer to your other question is a better approach. Please use that, instead of what you have. Program should be written to minimise doubling computations, and in a way that flows smoothly and intuitively. Think of it like water flowing through a pipe; data is the water, pipe is the code, the smoother and straighter the pipes, the faster the water flow.

Comment: In answer to your comment on where to find the error. The rule is to look at the last line of the traceback. All intermediate lines just show what happened in between: the path the program took from your line of code to the line that raised the error. Also, note that this is not a rule free of exceptions. There are lots of situations when the last line is not the real error, but let's not discuss those at the moment. For most of things like the question you asked, the last line will tell you the true error.

Comment: Also, an error can raise other errors. Which is what you are seeing when you run the code in your question. The KeyError is raised, but it was directly caused by the ValueError. If you read your traceback carefully, you'll see what I am saying.

Comment: @Kartik,i check the traceback info you mentioned.i copy the all message in the quesiton area above,i didn't find the ValueError you mentioned.Maybe I misunderstand something?