# Changing a table shape in python

Tags: python, pandas

i have a pandas dataframe suchs as:

```
            Price   Category    Product
4/11/2021   12  S1  ABC
4/12/2021   15  S1  ABC
4/13/2021   13  S2  ABC
4/14/2021   14  S3  ABC
4/11/2021   12  S1  CDE
4/12/2021   15  S1  CDE
4/13/2021   13  S2  CDE
4/14/2021   14  S3  CDE
4/11/2021   12  S1  FGH
4/12/2021   15  S1  FGH
4/13/2021   13  S2  FGH
4/14/2021   14  S3  FGH


and i would like to transform it to a shorter table so the result would like like:
           ABC  CDE FGH
4/11/2021   S1  S1  S1
4/12/2021   S1  S1  S1
4/13/2021   S2  S2  S2
4/14/2021   S3  S3  S3
```

NOte that the price column is not included.

In R i would use a `dcast` function but in Python i not know how to do it. I tried a 2-level loop and it is a disaster.

Anybody know a quick way in Python please?

Comment: What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: Out[8]: ['Price', 'Category', 'Product']

Comment: OK, so need `df = df.set_index('Product', append=True)['Category'].unstack()` ?

Comment: kindly have a look on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987231/why-did-i-get-a-keyerror-level-not-found

Comment: @jezrael, your solution works very well, super fast for me. i need to learn more about the setindex together with unstack. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you create a quick response so i put you the points please ?